# Postgres query doesn't get data when using AND operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to get data from a postgres database, using the AND operator but doesnt work.
If I exclude de AND using only `where items.name = 'Uptime'` or `where hstgrp.name like 'TEAM%'` I get the data, but when I combine them doesnt work, any ideas on how to solve this?

```
select history_uint.clock , history_uint.value , hstgrp.name , hosts.name 
FROM history_uint
join items on items.itemid = history_uint.itemid
join hosts on hosts.hostid = items.hostid
join hosts_groups on hosts_groups.hostid = hosts.hostid
join hstgrp on hstgrp.groupid = hosts_groups.groupid 
where items.name = 'Uptime'
and hstgrp.name like 'TEAM%'
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question which helps to explain the problem.

Comment: Obviously there are no rows that fulfill **both** requirements at the same time. Maybe you want an `OR` instead of the `AND`